# Java 2D arrays coin collection game from larger neigbouring cell

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, dynamic-arrays

My issue is the following:

I have a 2D array of size n x m, entered on a single line. On the next n lines there are m number of elements, that fill the array. So far so good.

There is a pawn on the field that always starts at the only 0 on the field (assuming there is always one 0).
It can move up and down, right and left. It always moves to the neighbouring cell with most coins and at each move collects 1 coin (=> empties the visited cell by 1). The pawn does this until there are only 0s around it and it can collect nothing anymore. I need to find the sum of all coins collected.

Here is a representation of first steps in Paint:

Coin Collection first steps:

[image]

Sample input: 
4 3, 3 2 4, 2 0 3, 1 1 5, 2 2 5 -> output: 22

Here is my code so far: 
I have some unfinished work with the targetCell (I still wonder how to get its coordinates dynamically in a loop, so that each cell with a larger value than the previous turns to a targetCell.) Also I'm stuck with using the directions I just created. Any hints would be useful for me to further develop the task.

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    String input = scanner.nextLine();
    String[] my_array = input.split(" ");
    int[] array = Arrays.stream(my_array).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
    int n = array[0]; // rows of matrix
    int m = array[1]; // cols of matrix

    int[][] matrix = new int[n][m];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        String[] numbers = line.split(" ");
        matrix[i] = new int[m];
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(numbers[j]);
        }
    }

    int startPoint = 0;
    int currentRow = 0;
    int currentCol = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            if (matrix[i][j] == 0) {
                startPoint = matrix[i][j];
                currentRow = i;
                currentCol = j;
            }
        }
    }

    int target1 = 0;
    int target2 = 0;
    int targetCell = 0;

            target1 = Math.max(matrix[currentRow - 1][currentCol], matrix[currentRow + 1][currentCol]);
            target2 = Math.max(matrix[currentRow][currentCol - 1], matrix[currentRow][currentCol + 1]);
            targetCell = Math.max(target1, target2);
            System.out.println(targetCell);

            int hDirection = 1;
            if (targetCol < currentCol) {
                hDirection = -1;
            }
            int vDirection = 1;
            if (targetRow < currentRow) {
                vDirection = -1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(Can't comment so will use an answer for now. Sorry)

My first thought would be to keep a global variable for the run so that when a coin is collected, it is added to its current value; similar to how you would keep score in games like Tetris. That's assuming I've read it right.

So something like:

```
private static int current_score = 0; //Assuming no use of objects so using static
```

Couldn't understand the sample input in this example. If you could give a three turn scenario of what the final score would be, I could give you better insight.